# Issue with reading date value from excel using apache poi, where date is formatted as string

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading excel file with Apache-poi API. In this for date column I read a cell value and convert it into date format. However, sometimes values in date cell are a string.

I am using following code for a date cell:

```
 if (row.getCell(cn).getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

        if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(cn))) {

            cell = row.getCell(cn);
            cellValue = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(cell.getDateCellValue());
        }
   }
```

How do I extend this to deal with the case where it is a string?

Comment: Please edit the post with the code you have used

Comment: Asking the question as directly as possible.

Comment: Why don't you first try to parse it as a date and if that fails parse it as String and then convert it to date?